# jqgrid cannot export to excel if data is grouped

Tags: php, jqgrid, export-to-excel

I have got a grid with data grouped by two columns.

Excel export is set to true:

```
$grid->setNavOptions('navigator', array("excel" => true, "add" => false, "edit" =>false, "del" => false, "search" => false, "refresh" => false));
```

and my table hasw UTF-8 encode

When i try to open the generated excel file the following message appear:

Problems came up in the following areas during load:
Table
this file cannot be opened because of errors.

I am using the jqSuite, the commercial version of the grid, not the open source one.

Can you help,

Thank you

Donato

Comment: Can you give an example of your excel sheet?

Comment: Hio Visser, thank you for your kind offer to help. You can download the file at: https://www.dropbox.com/s/d2uw7rkvq60cla1/exportdata%20%288%29.xml?v=0mcns